# Sending emails with outlook with files every month to same clients

Tags: python, email, automation, outlook, email-attachments

I send reports every month to clients with outlook. Every client has a report. So every client receives a different report depending on his performance of the month.

For now I send an email manually to every client attaching manually their report. That takes me around 1-2 days every month. I have about 100 clients meaning I send 100 emails every month manually.

I would like to automate that task every month with Python. I would like to use Outlook as I am using it today. I am learning Python for now.

Is there a way to automate that? The input info is:

- An email with the client's performance written in the email.
- An attached file with the whole report (sometimes multiple reports).
- Also have a double check that the report corresponds to the right client.

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can get the anwser you are looking for in https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.freecodecamp.org/news/send-emails-using-code-4fcea9df63f/amp/

There you can get informations about how the mechanics of using python for emails works and how to use it. Cheers!

Comment: Super usefull!! Thank you very much!